# Instantiating things in intent service

Tags: android, intentservice

I am using an intentservice for some purpose. I need to do two things when the service starts :

- use `getSystemService()` method to get some service.
- call a function of my custom application class by calling `getApplication()` . (This is to get the dagger application component, so that I can inject the dependencies in this class).

I tried doing both of these in the constructor, but both throw NPE. Maybe because *onCreate()* is not called till that point.
So, right now, I am doing it in *onHandleIntent()*.

But as we know, `onHandleIntent()` is called each time an intent is fired to start this service. So, these calls are made every time `onHandleIntent()` is called which I don't like. Functionally, I am able to achieve what I want, but I think there should be a way to do these things only once, when the service starts.

Is overriding `onCreate` of the intentservice a good place to do all this? or is there a better solution?

Comment: yes, do your stuff inside `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

So,

I ended up doing these things by overriding `onCreate()`, if that helps anyone.